# How to add custom tag to a header to make the font size larger in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, customization

I'm a self-taught novice seeking guidance from experts here.  I need help with defining CSS in WordPress to change the font size, color and weight of header on a website page.

**So far, the code I have is:**

```
<h2><strong><a style="color: #3f51b5">Text for the header I need to be 30 pixels large and in bold. The size here is still too small. </strong></h2>
```

**How do I change it so the font is 30 pixels large and bolder?**

Apologies if this was asked and answered before, but all my search results here did not specifically address my issue. I thank you in advance for your help. This is my first question to this group.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I did read that page. I thought I was following those instructions by first researching and then being specific with my needs.

Comment: Dear Paulie_D, Musa, Sparky, Gothdo, and ketan: I have edited my question. :-) FWIW, yesterday I received an answer from Lajos Arpad that solved my issue. You'll see it in the comments below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

1. I would add the following rule to the CSS file being used in the theme under your usage:

`.fs30 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}`

2. This would be the code needed in HTML:

`<h2><strong><a class="fs30" style="color: #3f51b5">Text for the header I need to be 30 pixels large and in bold. The size here is still too small. </strong></h2>`

If the style is not applied, then you have one of the following problems:

- your CSS file is not being used
- your CSS file is being cached
- a rule with higher priority overrides your rule for `fs30`

All these problem types are well-documented.

EDIT: You needed the following rule: `font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;` You can add the rule in several possible ways:

1. `style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;"` inside the tag header
2. `.fs30 {font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;}` inside a `<style>` tag
3. `.fs30 {font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;}` inside an external CSS file

For approaches 2. and 3. you will need to add the `class="fs30"` attribute to the target tag(s). Approach 1. is clearly inferior to approach 2. and 3., due to the following facts:

- the `style` attribute is not reusable, if you want to reuse it for another tag, you will have to copy it. If you have already copied it 200 times and you want to change the design, you will have to change it for all the 200 cases
- `style` attributes are structurally irrelevant, their purpose is solely design-related and unneededly makes your code messy
- if you want to study your design, then you will have to read HTML code as well, which you are not interested in when you study the design

So, instead of a `style` attribute, you clearly need a `style` tag or an external css file. However, external css files are superior compared to `style` tags. Your html code will be smaller this way, also, **very important** is that the css file will be cached by some browsers, reducing the size of data needed to be downloaded on further extractions, therefore your users will experience bigger speed, while your server will be more scalable. Not to mention the fact that external css files are more reusable than `style` tags, so you will duplicate only your link tag (1 line of code) instead of thousands of lines if needed.

Comment: I put that first fs30 rule in the CSS Stylesheet Editor, and the HTML code on the web page. The preview did not show any changes to the font size. I will research documentation for the possible problems you listed. :-(

Comment: @yja127, I hope you have a separate CSS file. If not, then add the relevant code into the style attribute, like this: <a style="color: #3f51b5; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;">. Also, you can test it by opening Chrome, right-clicking on the anchor, clicking on inspect element and on the right-bottom corner you see a panel where you can add/remove/edit CSS to check things out.

Comment: I added your suggested code in the WordPress page where the Header text appears, and it worked!!! The font is now larger and bolder. Thank you! Yay!! 

Now how do I let the Powers-that-be here know that your answer was perfect? I don't understand why others put my question on hold when you clearly understood what I needed and provided the correct code to resolve my issue.

Comment: @yja127, I am happy your issue has been solved. You can accept answers by clicking on the checkbox below the down-vote in general, but in this case you cannot do that, since the question is put on hold. I do not understand why was it put to hold, since I believe this is a pretty decent question, where you really tried to gather the necessary information and you specified your issue exactly as it was.

Comment: Lajos Arpad, if I click on the checkmark above, then it will look like the original answer you provided (with the .fs30 rule) solved my issue. It didn't. The code you provided in the above comment did the trick! I want others who have the same issue as I to see THAT answer as the correct one. Thank you for acknowledging my question was pretty decent, and that I specified my issue exactly as it was. Today I edited my question to the bare bones. I hope the hold will soon be lifted so you may provide a SECOND answer with the code that worked for me. I will then click that answer as the best.

Comment: @yja127, my answer is equivalent to the comment I have written, but it is superior to it, since it is a much better approach to separate css rules into a css file and load it instead of using inline styling as we used in this case. I will edit the answer to reflect the style attribute change as well, but it is equivalent to putting the same rules into a CSS class and using that class.